# css rotated text remove space

Tags: css, rotation, css-transforms

```html
 <h2><span style="display:inline-block;transform: rotate(90deg);" >###</span>Word</h2>
```

how can i remove the space between the rotated ### and word (you can see a gap between the objects if you highlight it)
I've tried playing with margin and padding but it makes no difference

Comment: you want ### and word close together?

Comment: For future reference, there's a (currently not very supported) CSS property for rotated text: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a negative value for *margin*.

```html
<h2><span style="display:inline-block;transform: rotate(90deg);margin:-10px;" >###</span>Word</h2>
```